# Wordpress: Calculate custom field values of all posts within a category?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom post type (product) , which includes a custom number field (rating). On a category (manufacturer) page I want to average those ratings to give an aggregate rating for the manufacturer.

So I am trying to build a function that returns a single value:

- retrieves the average value of all non-empty ratings fields found within the custom posts that are categorized with this category
- runs independently of the loop (I need to display before the loop and sometimes have more posts than are being used by the loop)

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: give us sample records with desired result `:D`

Comment: custom post type is product (product a, product b. ...), custom field is rating (57, 58, 99, ...). category (manufacturer a, manufacturer b, ...). The question is how can I query and average the rating field outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create custom template which you would apply to your Manufacturers page.  Outwith the main loop you would create a secondary loop using WP_Query. You then run through your custom post type and cumulate the ratings where they exist.  Set up a counter to calculate the average. Then use `wp_reset_query()` to reset the loop if necessary.

I've not tested the code below (obviously, I'm not going to go and set all that up), but it should give you enough of an idea that you can tweak/debug it to get the desired result;

I have created a fictitious category ID within you custom post type of 4 in this example, you can change it to whatever your setup is;

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$cumulative_value = 0;

$avg_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'cat' => '4' ));

if ( $avg_query->have_posts() ) :  
    while ($avg_query->have_posts()) : $avg_query->the_post(); 

        if ( $rating_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true) ) :

            $cumulative_value += $rating_value;
            $counter++;

        endif;

    endwhile;

endif;

$avg_value = $cumulative_value/$counter;

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Super awesome - works brilliantly after two minor modifications:
* For some reason I got irrational numbers with the ".=" -- I changed it to a foot soldierly '$cumulative_value = $cumulative_value + $rating_value;' and it works beautifully
* category id replaced with $cat - it's specific to the individual ID
Where can I give 100 points?? :)

Comment: Lol - that's excellent.  The irrational numbers must have came from me adding a string to a number so it must have been concatenating it. It should be cast as a number explictly using (int).  Have updated the post.

Comment: Haha - I looked for that, but at least the result didn't look concatenated, or it maxed out... btw I tried but it doesn't work the way you changed it to; brackets and also int isn't defined

Comment: D'oh! What a mistake-a to make-a. +=

Comment: So how do we display this average value?

Comment: @Pete - `echo $avg_value;`